# Handling Select option in PHP in case of many drop-down menu

Tags: php, javascript, html

In the following code, I am trying to handle the select option or the value of the text field:

```
<script>
function check() {
    var dropdown = document.getElementById("OpType");
    var current_value = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;

    if (current_value == "OpNo") {
        document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "none";
        <?php $TPE = '1'?>
    }
    else if (current_value == "OpTyp") {
        document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "none";
        <?php $TPE = '2'?>
    }
    else if (current_value == "OpMem") {
        document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "none";
        <?php $TPE = '3'?>
    }
    else if (current_value == "OpEmp"){
        document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "block";
        <?php $TPE = '4'?>
    }
    else if (current_value == "blank") {
        document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "none";
        <?php $TPE = '0'?>
    }
}
</script>

<form name="f1" action="FollowOperations.php" method="post">
<select id="OpType" onChange="check();">
<option value="blank">Choose</option>
<option value="OpNo">Operation No</option>
<option value="OpTyp">Operation Type</option>
<option value="OpMem">Maintenance Member</option>
<option value="OpEmp">Employee</option>
</select><br>

<input class="tb10" type="text" id="operationno" size="4" style="text-align: center" style="display: none">
                         
<select id="MainType" style="display: none">
<option value="blank">Choose</option>
<option value="printing">Printing</option>
<option value="maintenance">PC Maintenance</option>
<option value="internet">Internet Problem</option>
<option value="software">Software</option>
<option value="email">Email Problem</option>
<option value="usbcd">USB/CD Problem</option>
</select>

<select id="MemName" style="display: none">
<option value="blank">Choose</option>
<option value="john">John</option>
<option value="hen">Hen</option>
</select>
                         
<select id="EmpName" style="display: none">
<option value="blank">Choose</option>
<option value="smith">Smith</option>
<option value="will">William</option>
<option value="Gor">George</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" /> 
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])){

if ($TPE == '1'){

$operationno = $_POST['operationno'];
$query_retrieve_maintenance = "Select Type from Maintenance where ID = '$operationno'";
$result_retrieve_maintenance = mysqli_query($dbh, $query_retrieve_maintenance);
$maintenance_type = mysqli_fetch_row($result_retrieve_maintenance);
$maintenance_typet = $maintenance_type[0];
echo $maintenance_typet;

} else if ($TPE == '2'){

$MainType = $_POST['MainType'];
if ($MainType=='email'){echo 'Email is not ava';}

} else if ($TPE == '3'){

$MemName = $_POST['MemName'];

} else if ($TPE == '4'){

$EmpName = $_POST['EmpName'];

} else{

$msg = 'not available';
}
}
?>
```

As you can see in the code, when a user selects operation no, a text field will show up and then the user will enter the operation no to show the type of this maintenance operation. Similarly, when the user selects operation type, the list of maintenance types will show up so that the user selects the type of the operation that he needs and so on for the rest of select options.

The problem that I am facing is handling what the user selects or enters (in case of searching by operation no). As you can see in the code, I used `if (isset($_POST['formsubmitted'])){` but it didn't work. Any suggestions guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see your example:

```
if (current_value == "OpNo") {
    document.getElementById("operationno").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("MainType").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("MemName").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("EmpName").style.display = "none";
    <?php $TPE = '1'?>
}
```

You paste PHP code into javascript. But `<?php $TPE = '1'?>` and all others statement like that will be all executed by PHP, not depending on conditions of javascript.

You can perform sequence:

`If something happened in PHP (on server) -> then execute some code of javascript (on client)`
Because you will be able to decide what JS code client should execute.

But cannot:

`If something happened in Javascript(client) -> execute code of PHP(server)` unless you send xmlhttp requests to a webpage.

So in your case your `$TPE` will be always `0`.

What I suggest is:
1. Put your data into array for mapping, you can then improve it:

```
$data = array(
  "OpNo" => 1,
  "OpTye" => 2,
  "OpMem" => 3,
  "OpEmp" => 4,
  "blank" => 5
);
```

Then make your selection usable in a form, creating attribute `name`

```
<select id="OpType" name="tpe" onChange="check();">
<option value="blank">Choose</option>
<option value="OpNo">Operation No</option>
<option value="OpTyp">Operation Type</option>
<option value="OpMem">Maintenance Member</option>
<option value="OpEmp">Employee</option>
</select><br>
```

Then at last, get that TPE value from `$_POST`

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['tpe'])){
      if ((int) $_POST['tpe'] === $data['OpNo']){
        //Do your stuff.
      ?>
        <script>
          executeSomeJSFunctionsHere();
        </script>
      <?php
      }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The formsubmitted name is missing from your input submit :

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button" name="formsubmitted" />
```

This should work.